# Is the lack of independent variables a problem in a fixed effects regression?

Tags: fixed-effects-model

I am currently working on a research project for my Master's degree. I use panel data at the country-month level but I have a problem of data availability regarding my topic, because besides my variable of interest, I cannot find other predictors that vary monthly.

I am now facing a dilemma between:

- Doing a fixed-effect regression with just two independent variables (because I cannot find enough time-varying variables regarding my topic that vary both across country and across months)
- Removing the country fixed effects to include more time-invariant independant variables but loosing the advantages of removing the within-unit heterogeneity.

I don't want my assignment to look empty but I still wanted to ask : Is it fine to just have two independent variables if I can justify the lack of data availability?

Comment: Welcome. Just how important is it to restrict attention to “within country” variation? How many countries did you sample? Will you pursue a random effects estimator?